# Java's comma separator - does it force an evaluation order?

Tags: java, comma-operator

I'm writing a loop to make multiple fragments out of a byte array, where the first fragment must be a different size from later fragments.

```
for (int frag_start = 0, frag_end = Math.min(len, MAX_FIRST_FRAG_SIZE);
     frag_start < len;
     frag_start = frag_end, frag_end = Math.min(len, frag_start + MAX_LATER_FRAG_SIZE)) {
     // code goes here
}
```

Does the comma in `frag_start = frag_end, frag_end = ...` enforce that the assignment, before the comma, will always happen ahead of the assignment after the comma, or is the JVM free to reorder those operations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Java, the evaluation of expressions separated by the comma operator `,` is strictly from left to right. Each expression within a comma is evaluated fully before moving to the next one.

Note that the comma operator has the lowest precedence of any operator.

Comment: [Here's the link to the relevant bit of the language specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.1.1): _"the expressions are evaluated in sequence from left to right"_